# Probability Theory/Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems

Hi guys i have two questions i´m struggling with.

1)The mean duration of education for a population is 12 years and
the standard deviation is 2 years. What is the maximum probability that a randomly selected individual will have had less than
9 or more than 15 years of education?

2)Limit Theorem: A firm receives 100 applications for a vacant
job. Assume that the invitation to a job interview is
i.i.d (Bernoulli). Further, imagine that the probability of being
invited to an interview is 1/2. What is the probability that the
number of applications accepted for interview is larger than 65?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. **In other words:** It would be helpful if you show us **exactly where and why** you are struggling with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"1)The mean duration of education for a population is 12 years and the standard deviation is 2 years. What is the maximum probability that a randomly selected individual will have had less than 9 or more than 15 years of education?"

Look up the probabilities of X< (9- 12)/2 and X> (15-12)/2 in a table of the **standard normal distribution** and add them.  Wikipedia has one here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table.

Answer (score 0):

1) Let $X$ be the number of years of education of the selected individual.  "$X < 9$ or $X > 15$" is equivalent to $|X-12| > 3$.   I think we may safely assume that the probability that the individual has exactly 9 or 15 years of education is zero, so $\Pr(|X-12| > 3) = \Pr(|x-12| \ge 3)$.  By [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Probabilistic_statement), 
$$\Pr\left(|X-2)| \ge \frac{3}{2} \cdot 2\right) \le \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2$$
i.e. the maximum probability is $(2/3)^2$.

We could give a tighter bound if we knew the distribution of the number of years of education, for example if we knew it was a Normal distribution, but the problem statement does not specify the distribution, and in this case there does not seem to be any reason to assume a Normal distribution.